# How to add multiple models from a Django app to adminpanel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

To add a single model from an app in to the `/admin` area I have done like so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from wiki.models import Page, Category, CategoryItem

# register Pages for use in Django admin
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

which works fine for a single model, but when I try to register the other two (Category and CategoryItem), it breaks down. What is the correct way of adding multiple models for a single Django app in the admin interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in django 1.5 we do following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from wiki.models import Page, Category, CategoryItem


for cls in (Page, Category, CategoryItem):
    admin.site.register(cls)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is default way:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class CategoryItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(CategoryItem, CategoryItemAdmin)
```

If you've got some unhandled exception, add it to the question, so we can find out what's broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not making changes in the models display in admin portal no need to create Admin Items, you can pretty much register it like :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from wiki.models import Page, Category, CategoryItem

admin.site.register(Page)
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(CategoryItem)
```